# Quip API api function edit_document with AFTER_SECTION flag

Tags: api, quip

I believe there might be a bug in the API implementation of threads/edit-document and I was curious if anybody else had run into this or can see what I'm doing wrong. When calling the api edit_document function with AFTER_SECTION operation and a defined section_id the api returns: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error. No error is returned after the more simple APPEND or PREPEND operations are used. furthermore the APPEND operation is not functioning as expected as it is sometimes appended and other times prepended just below the First Large Header. 
example(obviously the code below won't run.  This is only the relevant code):

```
# Edit operations
APPEND, \
PREPEND, \
AFTER_SECTION, \
BEFORE_SECTION, \
REPLACE_SECTION, \
DELETE_SECTION = range(6)

def _fetch_json(self, path, post_data=None, **args):
    request = Request(url=self._url(path, **args))
    if post_data:
        post_data = dict((k, v) for k, v in post_data.items()
                         if v or isinstance(v, int))
        request.data = urlencode(self._clean(**post_data)).encode("utf-8")
    if self.access_token:
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + self.access_token)
    try:
        return json.loads(
            urlopen(request, timeout=self.request_timeout).read().decode('utf-8'))
    except HTTPError as error:
        try:
            # Extract the developer-friendly error message from the response
            message = json.loads(error.read())["error_description"]
        except Exception:
            raise error
        if (self.retry_rate_limit and error.code == 503 and
            message == "Over Rate Limit"):
            # Retry later.
            reset_time = float(error.headers.get("X-RateLimit-Reset"))
            delay = max(2, reset_time - time.time() + 1)
            logging.warning("Rate Limit, delaying for %d seconds", delay)
            time.sleep(delay)
            return self._fetch_json(path, post_data, **args)
        else:
            raise QuipError(error.code, message, error)

def edit_document(self, thread_id, content, operation=APPEND, format="html", 
section_id=None, **kwargs): 
    """Edits the given document, adding the given content. 
    `operation` should be one of the constants described above. If 
    `operation` is relative to another section of the document, you must 
    also specify the `section_id`. 
    """ 
    args = { 
        "thread_id": thread_id, 
        "content": content, 
        "location": operation, 
        "format": format, 
        "section_id": section_id, 
    } 
    args.update(kwargs) 
    return self._fetch_json("threads/edit-document", post_data=args) 

masterID = "ZHt3AmtaaMH4" 
section_id = "HTQACAMakxv" 
sheetTemplateID = "pHgkAr8FienY" 
copySheet = client.get_thread(sheetTemplateID).get("html") 
client.edit_document(masterID,copySheet,operation="AFTER_SECTION",section_id=section_id)
```